# How can I capture all the argument names of a c++ function's declaration/prototype?

Tags: c++, parsing

I need to capture all the names of the arguments of some C++ function prototypes.

I was able to write a bare-bone regex to capture C functions (just to play around, I **do not intend to use regex** on the final solution),
but it goes out the window for more complex declarations.

This is easy for simple functions, like this:

```
void hello(int a);
```

But then comes C++. Here is one complicated example from CUDA:

```
extern __host__ cudaError_t CUDARTAPI cudaStreamGetCaptureInfo(cudaStream_t stream, enum cudaStreamCaptureStatus *captureStatus_out, unsigned long long *id_out __dv(0), cudaGraph_t *graph_out __dv(0), const cudaGraphNode_t **dependencies_out __dv(0), size_t *numDependencies_out __dv(0));
```

Which is a beast of a C++ line (I'm not a fan).

I'd like to capture the following:

> stream, captureStatus_out, id_out, graph_out, dependencies_out, numDependencies_out

How can I achieve this? I'm using Python but any tool, compiler or language is fine.

I don't want to be rude, but I'm not looking for answers like: "don't use regex, use clang" or some other insanely big and complex compiler. This is clearly **not** a problem for regex. At least post some pointers to where one could start reading about a solution.

Bonus: assuming an AST will be used, if the solution to this problem could say if a line (multiple-line definitions do not need to be considered) is a function definition or not, that would be even better.

Comment: Parsing C++ really should be done with a C++ compiler.  Get one that can output what you want.

Comment: I've a C compiler with regex - you can look into the part parsing declarations if you want - https://github.com/AnFunctionArray/cperllexer/blob/main/typename.regex . Although that is still a complete solution because you need to capture types anyway (but at least you could potentially modify it for your needs - however you would need Perl).

Comment: That C++ line could just as well be C, I see nothing C++-specific in it.

Comment: My first thought was to use the LLVM libraries to capture this. It seems like something one could write a clang-tidy check to capture, so it should be possible to write a standalone tool - look into [LibTooling](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html).

Comment: @JesperJuhl thank you for the pointer, it looks like I'll have to throw myself into the compiler abyss. Btw, I think it's the first answer of this type of problem that *actually has* a link to something.

Comment: It's also worth noting that libclang has python bindings, and clang has some cli utils such as ast-dump and clang-query. For completeness

Comment: Doxygen was doing that by using BISON, afaik, and what they can pull out of C++ standard. Although it's not idea, because many possible options present in C++ in regard to function parameters. In general case even separating type from name might be non-trivial. On other hand this doesn't appear to be actually a C++ line, it got unsupported syntax - the `(0)`

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie doxygen was the way to go. It took some manual cleaning, though.

Comment: No [tag:compiler-construction] here. You are not constructing a compiler (which is the problem). Don't tag indiscrimately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learning an entire compiler framework was out of the question due to the steep learning curve, so I looked for things that already used compiler tools.

Doxygen was the way to go. I generate xml of the header file, then iterate through the tree using `xml.etree.ElementTree`, looking for `memberdef` and `kind="function"`.
Doxygen produces the function name, names and types of arguments.
Example:

```
<type>__host__ cudaError_t CUDARTAPI</type>
 <definition>__host__ cudaError_t CUDARTAPI cudaStreamGetCaptureInfo</definition>
<name>cudaStreamGetCaptureInfo</name>
<param>
   <type>cudaStream_t</type>
   <declname>stream</declname>
</param>
```

But Doxygen does not like the `__dv` stuff, so I just manually cleaned up the header file, removing `__dv(arg)` with `arg` using regex. It is definitely not applicable to every case, but it works for mine.